# How do I split a Bootcamp Partition on a second drive?

Tags: bootcamp, mac-mini, partition

I have a Mac Mini Server 2011, which has 2 Hard disks of 750GB  each.
I want to install Windows 7 on the second disk, but i want to split this disk on two partitions: One of 450 GB for Windows and one of 300 GB with exFat to share data between Windows and OS X (is Lion by the way).

I tried with the Bootcamp assistant, but it took for the Bootcamp partition the whole disk, and so I installed that way, but I prefer to have both partitions as I mentioned above.

Can I split it the way I want? I don't mind if I have to reinstall Windows as long as I have the best compatible solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Open Disk Utility and format second HDD with Partition Map Scheme to be Master Boot Record.
Then start up from Windows Install Disk by pressing Alt or C and create partitions from there.

You should probably use Bootcamp Assistant before (or after) just to save Windows drivers and Bootcamp taskbar utility to the flash disk or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Should work without problems, but didn't try: Open Disk Utility. Create two partitions, an exFAT-partition and a mac-partition. Then, start bootcamp assistant and use the mac partition to install windows.

Comment: This doesn't work. On boot camp assistant, when I choose the disk, the only available options are: "Erase disk and create a single partition for Windows" and "Restore Disk to Single Mac OS Partition"

Comment: Did you try resizing the windows partition in Windows 7 (rightclick on computer -> Manage -> Disk Manager), rebooting to Mac OS and creating the exFAT partition in disk utility? As far as I read from [a guide on macrumors](http://guides.macrumors.com/Extend/Resize_Boot_Camp_Partition) this should be possible.

Comment: With the Disk Manager in Windows you can't resize an existing partition. You can delete them, and make new ones, but no resize them.

Comment: @DkAngelito you're wrong, since XP you can make them bigger, since Vista also shrink it.

Comment: Well, I didn't know that I could shrink a partition in the Device Manager. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Nope, I didn't work. After shrinking the partition and rebooting Windows fails to load. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: I guess that's something with the partition table synchronization. One more idea: create two NTFS partitions while installing windows and reformat one (in windows) to exFAT before rebooting to Mac.

Comment: i Can't create two partitions. If I delete the bootcamp partition, Windows will not boot (Its in the boot camp manual and i have test it).